# Anaconda not recognizing local directories in pytest

Tags: python, anaconda, pytest

I'm trying to set up my tests in Anaconda with Python 3.8.5 and pytest 6.1.1. I'm running into a problem where anaconda won't import from my local directory structure. I'm running other code in this directory structure and I've double checked my directory and file names, copying and pasting from working code.

ETA: I've also added empty __ init __.py files to each directory -- empty because there are no special instructions for importing the whole module -- but that has not changed the behavior.

In the __ main __ program itself, I'm using

```
import sys
from os import getcwd
root_dir = getcwd()
moduledir = root_dir  + '\\modules'
sys.path.append(moduledir)
```

But I have the fond notion that this shouldn't be necessary in the tests.

I have this directory structure:

```
--/tests
    test_mod1.py
--/my_modules
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
```

and test_mod1 starts off with

```
import pytest
from mod1 import function_to_test
```

but when I run pytest in the root directory I get the error message

```
..\..\anaconda3a\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_mod1.py:2: in <module>
   from mod1 import function_to_test
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'
```

If I change that import statement to

`from my_modules.mod1 import function_to_test`

I get the same error, but this time it's not finding my_modules.

If I add a period before the import statment

`from .my_modules.mod1 import function_to_test`

then the error spew is the same except that the last line is

`E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I also tried migrating the test file to the my_modules directory. mod1 starts off by importing from mod2 (mod2 has a bunch of app-wide constants). In this case, pytest successfully finds mod1, but not mod2 and I get that error spew but with the second import flagged:

```
..\..\anaconda3a\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
mod1.py:3: in <module>
   from mod2 import app_constants
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod2'
```

I've recently run pytest successfully with my current distro, running tests from the same directory as the module I'm testing; but the modules had no further dependencies. So pytest itself seems to run fine as long as I'm not asking it to look in other directories, but now I want to be able to test the whole app at once (and test these more complex modules).

Comment: *"anaconda won't import from ..."* This doesn't make sense. Anaconda is a Python distribution; it doesn't really *do* anything. Do you mean *Python* won't import local modules?

Comment: Hi, Merv! I'm happy to agree that it doesn't make sense. The first line of the big error message wasn't showing because it was on the same line as my triple-tick:-) So I've corrected that. It looks like Python running code inside Anaconda's library of conda-installed moules in its attempt to import the module.   It's searching for the file to import only there and not finding it, rather than looking in the subdirectories of the cwd., Jupyter finds the files just fine, but somehow not pytest.

Comment: I've ETAed the question to also mention that I'm running my main program (and Jupyter notebooks) just fine using some code to add the cwd to PATH, but I hadn't thought that I'd need to do that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your tests via the ***pytest*** tool, the behavior of your imports are determined by how the Python path (`sys.path`) is configured by the ***pytest*** tool.  I took a look at what it does, and it appears that it adds the directory containing a particular test's code to `sys.path`.  So, in your case, it adds the `tests` directory to `sys.path`.  Since the rest of your code is not in/below this directory, you aren't going to be able to import any of it from your test code.

What you need to do is add a directory to `sys.path` such that your imports resolve correctly.  In your case, you want to add your `my_modules` directory to `sys.path`.  You can do that at the top of your test file, before you attempt to import your own module, like this:

```
# test_mod1.py

import sys
import os

# Compute the absolute path to our my_modules directory starting from the directory containing this file
modules_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'my_modules'))

# Add our my_modules directory to the Python path
sys.path.append(modules_path)

from mod1 import function_to_test

def test1():
    r = function_to_test()
    assert r == 10024
```

To cause this test to run and succeed, I created your other two files as so:

```
# mod1.py

import mod2

def function_to_test():
    r = mod2.mod2_function()
    r += 10000
    return r


# mod2.py

def mod2_function():
    return 24
```

There are other ways that you could cause `sys.path` to contain the path to your `my_modules` directory, like by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable before executing the test.